# Looking to automatically replace http:// with https:// for any pasted URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to use a function/script in Google Sheets that will look at a column where folks are pasting URLs and take any links with http:// and replace them with https://

This is for a UTM link building spreadsheet and I want to make sure we are using secure URLs every time.

Any insight would be awesome!!

I tried to use the following script but had no success

```
  var FILE = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xyz");
  var CONTENT = FILE.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var A1 = CONTENT.getRange("I17");
  A1.createTextFinder(".").replaceAllWith("");
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief descrition of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Create an `onEdit` trigger to change the value when a cell in the column is edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const col = 1 // change this to your column; A=1, B=2, Z=26, etc
  if (e.range.getColumn() != col) return

  const regEx = /^http:\/\//
  e.range.setValue(e.value.replace(regEx, "https://"))
}
```

Example:
[image]